# VB.net - Fetch rows of data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been trying to fetch records that I have in my database but it's not working as of yet. Tried to search some codes. It worked on them but not on mine.

```
 Try
        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(Surname, ', ', FirstName) as 'Name' FROM tbl_ClassList", cn)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Do While reader.Read
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Item("Name").ToString())
        Loop

        reader.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Wrong")
    End Try
```

Comment: Was there any exception ?

Comment: No. As if it doesn't do anything nor say what's wrong.

Comment: have you open the connection and did not paste that code in your question !? @JohnAnthony

Comment: Use `Using` keyword for `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader`, then you can get rid of `Close` and `Dispose` methods

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to open your connection:

```
Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
cn.Open()
```

Comment: and we can use `if not(cn.ping()) then cn.open()` for connections that opened before and may be closed now.

Comment: @MohaMad, No need in OP case, because he creates new connection just before using